# Switch from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with using Fragments within an Activity. I'd like to step into a Fragment from the Activity and I'm very close to do this. Here is my Activity:

```
Utils u;
Fragment fragment;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.galleryID);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                Utils.fragmentManager(frameLayout.getId(), fragment, MainActivity.this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Utils:

```
public class Utils {
public static void fragmentManager(Integer contentId, Fragment fragment, Activity activity) {
    try {
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(contentId, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

GalleryFragment:

```
 public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_galleryfragment, parent, false);
}

// This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
// Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
}
```

}

And my xmls
activity_main:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/galleryID"
    android:text="gallery"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the fragment_galleryfragment.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/ok">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the GALLERY button the layout of the gallery appears on the screen. But the activity_main layout stays where it is. I'd like to switch layout like switching from Activity A to Activity B. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you would like to do? Do want to start another fragment from your fragment? or from your activity once the fragment is displayed you want to show another fragment?

Comment: You are changing the content of the framelayout when replacing the fragment, so the rest of the elements in the activity will remain. You have to hide them programmatically, or make your activity to contain just your framelayout and use two fragments (the initial one containing the gallery button and your gallery fragment)

Comment: Or you could hide the button using the buttonsetVisibility(false) Once the button is pressed.

Comment: @LuisMiguelSierra these two fragments should be inside the framelayout?

Comment: You should replace them in your framelayout. Just put the gallery button in a new fragment and show it like you are doing with your gallery fragment on the onCreate of your activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
//instead of this
FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
```

rest of your code looks correct.

You should use

> getSupportFragmentManager()

if you're using

> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

and if you are using

> android.app.FragmentManager

then you should use

> getFragmentManager()

Comment: Cannot resolve this method. Doesn't give me anything to import.

Comment: also make sure you hide other contents of the activity(except the framelayout) using : setVisibility(View.GONE); or setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); according to your use.

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity_main like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/galleryID"
    android:text="gallery"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In fragment_galleryfragment.xml, make your LinearLayout clickable, and change its background if your ok drawable not fully cover your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace whole activity's layout, just put button inside your framelayout and your framelayout will be replaced with your fragment's layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/galleryID"
                  android:text="gallery"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>


  </RelativeLayout>
```